# Clickhouse dynamic query with python

Tags: python, clickhouse

I have a case where I want the user to enter the query parameters for WHERE clause in the input screen, then Clickhouse should run the query based on that. I was planning to use something like this, unfortunately it doesn't work.

```py
from clickhouse_driver import Client
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
    
client = Client('localhost', settings={'use_numpy': True})
    
start_date = '2022-07-31',
end_date = '2022-08-31'
    
df= client.query_dataframe('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE Date >= {start_date} AND Date <= {end_date}')

# start_date and end_date in the query are the variable value defined above.
# Expecting to run the query based on the variables value.
```

Comment: The query string is missing the formatting prefix "f", which would allow it to use the variable values, i.e.: ```df= client.query_dataframe(f'SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE Date >= {start_date} AND Date <= {end_date}')```

Answer (score 0):

look documentation
https://clickhouse-driver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#selecting-data

```py
df= client.query_dataframe(
 'SELECT * FROM mytable ' +
 ' WHERE Date >= %(start_date)s AND Date <= %(end_date)s', 
 {'start_date': start_date, 'end_date': end_date}
)
```